# virtualClasspath equivalent in tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am deploying instance of tomcat 8 and trying to find equivalent of virtualClasspath.

Below is the snippet of configuration descriptor I had in Tomcat 7,

`<Context path="/path">
        <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"         virtualClasspath="/home/kedar/third_party_jars/*.jar" />
</Context>`

How can I specify the similar thing in tomcat 8. To be more specific, how to include multiple third party jars(as above) under classpath in the configuration descriptor of tomcat 8?

We can include each jar one by one in the following way, but I am looking some regex kind of way to include multiple jars.

`<Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
        <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet"
            base="/home/kedar//third_party_lib/xyz.jar"
            internalPath="/" 
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
</Resouces>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding external resources to class-path in Tomcat 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143697/adding-external-resources-to-class-path-in-tomcat-8)

Comment: I have already checked that link, but that does not seems to work for me either.
`  <Context path="/path">
<Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/home/kedar/CVS/third_party_lib"
            internalPath="/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />'
</Context>`

Althought, the instance starts, application is unable to find third party jars at runtime.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you set `webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib"`? As it's where all the jars are stored.