# Custom Shared jars in TomEE

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, apache-tomee

Trying to have unique jars for each application, so using

> "org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader

configuration in context.xml. The application is an EAR, deployed in 'apps' folder under TomEE install directory. context.xml is in

/apps/myApp/META-INF/

but the jars are not visible to app. Question is,

1) is this the right location? or should it be in META-INF of the webApp inside ear - /apps/myApp/webApp/META-INF

2) VirtualWebappLoader is only for webApps and for EAR under apps?

Comment: Which version of tomcat do you use? The use of the `VirtualWebappLoader` has changed with Tomcat 8 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143697/adding-external-resources-to-class-path-in-tomcat-8).

Comment: I am using TomEE 1.7.1 on linux. Is this equivalent to Tomcat 8?