# Tomcat custom context.xml file is never taken into account

Tags: java, css, tomcat, tomcat8

I have currently a problem with the Tomcat configuration of a web application (I use Tomcat 8.5.57).
This web application is packaged in a war file containing, among others, html files and css files.
This application works well.

Now, I have a request from a customer asking to be able to modify the look and feel of the application from outside of the war via a custom css file managed by the client (used to set the logo of the client or stuff like that).
So I tried to create a custom context file, called `custom.xml`, that I placed in `tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost` directory.
This file looks like :

```
<Context    docBase="E:/somedirectory/support" 
            path="/app/css" 
            reloadable    = "false"
            unpackWAR     = "false"
            swallowOutput = "true" >
                <WatchedResource>custom.css</WatchedResource>           
</Context>
```

I put the `custom.css` file containing some css instructions as test in the `E:/somedirectory/support` directory.
In the html file of my web application, I have the following line in the head section :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
```

The problem is that my `custom.css` file is never taken into account.

When I open the Sources tab of Chrome's developer tools, I see a `custom.css` file in the hierarchy in `app/css` as expected (probably due to the line in the html file), but it is hopelessly empty.
I tried a lot of things found on the Web and on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me...

Can someone help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding external resources to class-path in Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143697/adding-external-resources-to-class-path-in-tomcat-8)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't.  
  
I tried some configurations like this :   

`<Context>
    <Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="C:\\PROJECT_NAME\\conf"
            internalPath="/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    </Resources>
</Context>`

But it doesn't work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` attribute of `<Context>` element is ignored outside of `server.xml`:

> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase. [from [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)]

Therefore you have two choices:

- You can define a new context (new web application) with context path `/app/css` by creating a file named `conf\Catalina\localhost\app#css.xml` and content:

```xml
<Context docBase="E:\somedirectory\support" />
```

This way **everything** under the `/app/css` subtree will **only** be served from the `E:\somedirectory\support` directory.

2. You can redefine your application context to include an additional virtual directory (beside the contents of the WAR file) by adding a file named `conf\Catalina\localhost\app.xml` with content:

```xml
<Context>
  <Resources>
    <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                  base="E:\somedirectory\support"
                  webAppMount="/css" />
  </Resources>
</Context>
```

This way, while serving a request for `/app/css/foo/bar`, Tomcat will first look for `foo/bar` in `E:\somedirectory\support` and then in the WAR file.

Comment: I tried solution 2 and it works perfectly ! Thanks a lot.